# How to count records, deleted via JDBC executeBatch in Oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

```
int[] res = stmt.executeBatch();
```

Problem: all values in the res array will be "-2" for Oracle.
For inserts you can simply get the res array size as number of records inserted.
For deletes - whether delete was successful or not, result remains the same, therefore you can't compute the number of records actually deleted (or updated).

Any other way to do this in a straight delete? (without a lookup)

Comment: For the record, -2 is `Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with release 12.1, the Oracle JDBC returns the row count for Array DML. See details @ https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraperf.htm#CHDCDBCH

Comment: Empty DELETE (the one that did not delete anything) will return an array entry, just like a happened delete, so the issue prevails - can't determine how many records have been altered, using the method you are describing.